# How to prevent overflow of sessions in node.js app?

Tags: node.js, security, session, express, owasp

I have a nodejs web application which uses the express framework, and it is reachable via internet.
I am using a session store which stores the sessions as plain files on disk, and with the current implementation, each request without cookie will get a new session-id, resulting in a new file on disk for the new session.

Since the application is reachable via internet, I receive a lot of invalid requests, which of course never send cookies, but produce more sessions on my filesystem, which is a real mess.

I used the OWASP session management cheat sheet as a guideline for the implementation (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet), but it does not cover the topic of guest sessions in detail. It only states that applications might find it useful to assign sessions also to unauthenticated (guest) users, so guest-sessions seem to be a valid feature in general.

So right now I dont know how to properly fight the problem of unnecessarily created sessions/session files by invalid/malicious requests. Is there any recommended way to do this?
I thought of maybe a combination of a very short expiration of 'guest'-sessions (< 5min) and a whitelist for IP ranges or something, where any IP not in the whitelist will not receive a guest-session (but of course a session once successfully authenticated).

Any tips on how I should approach this problem?

Comment: why you believe that creating and storing session in plain files is secure way ? session are best stored in memory/cache server marked with an expiration date. Also if you receive many invalid requests try throttling the IP or maybe even ban that certain IP. Either way I believe you are overthinking it and adding so many precautions that will make your application unmaintainable. Try modules like helmet and read articles about securing express applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of how you store your session you will face this same issue. At some point your session storage will overflow (run out of disk space, run out of ram, run out of inodes etc).

What you need to do is prune your sessions. Unless you really can afford to store sessions indefinitely you should set an expiry date on your session cookie. For the client the browser will take care of deleting the cookie. For the server you need to periodically check all sessions to see if any have expired.

What you do next is simple. Regardless of the technology you choose to store sessions you simply delete expired sessions. This can be done either within your node process (inside some `setTimeout()` handler) or outside your node process (maybe a simple daily cron job).

You should allow some grace period (1 minute, 1 hour, 1 day etc.) before deleting stale session files to prevent race condition between you deleting the session file and a user loading the website.

You may also want to allow users to refresh the session expiry date on each visit. For a file-based session store this can be as simple as touching the file to update last modified time.

There is one situation where this strategy won't work. Some databases won't release disk space when you delete data for performance reasons (MySQL with InnoDB for example). Instead the data is simply marked as deleted but the database keep growing. In such cases your only way out is to change your session storage. But since you are using file storage it's not an issue you need to worry about.

Comment: You got some good points here. I already have session timeouts and cyclic checks, as required by OWASP (idle timeout, absolute timeout, automatic renewal). It will delete sessions according to those timeouts. But the application requirements include a pretty long lifespan of authenticated user sessions, and thus, guest sessions are currently also affected.
Maybe I should therefore introduce a separate (short) timeout of guest sessions, combined with not storing guest sessions to persistency.

Comment: @user826955: Yes, that's how it's done. Typically not logged in users will far exceed logged in users once your website becomes popular. Especially once your website gets indexed by google. It will be crawled by several other crawlers if you get yourself on google. At minimum there will be Bing, Yahoo and Baidu

Answer (score 1):

The best session storage for your use case would be Redis, Memcached or some other fast in-memory data store, but note that all of your session data will have to fit in RAM.

Another option would be to use a disk-based database like any RDBMS or Mongo, Couch, Rethink etc. but make sure that it's fast or otherwise your performance will degrade tremendously.

The fastest way with highest scalability characteristics would be to not store any session data on your server and instead rely on data sent in cookies or other client-side storage, e.g. using JWT - see: https://jwt.io/ - but note that this way you will not have control over once issued session tokens unless you introduce a database to check if they are valid or not and a mechanism of invalidating them, but at this point you have the same problems as with storing that data on the server, maybe with an exception that there could be potentially less data to store and that it wouldn't have to be updated often.

Every approach here has some pros and cons but storing data in the files on the file system is never an optimal solution for production for any data, not only for session data. You should use a database for that or store data on the client if the disadvantages of that are acceptable in your use case.

Comment: As you already mentioned, and as mentioned by @slebetman, the storage technology is irrelevant, as any possible technology will overflow at some point.
I want to stick with server side session storage, as this is (at least for my understanding/research/knowledge) more secure, and also recommended by OWASP.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that you want to avoid:

```
app.use(session({ ... }));
app.use(express.static(...));
```

That would create sessions for all static requests.

You can mitigate that by disabling the [`saveUninitialized` setting](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#saveuninitialized):

```
app.use(session({
  saveUninitialized : false,
  ...
}));
app.use(express.static(...));
```

That will prevent new-but-unmodified sessions to be stored. Because static resources don't modify sessions, no sessions will be created for them.

Another option would be to enable sessions for only a subset of your routes:

```
const session = require('express-session');

let sessionMiddleware = session({ ... });

app.use('/api', sessionMiddleware, apiRouter);
```

Comment: While I am using custom implementations of the session management (and no express ession middleware, as per company requirements), I like the idea of not flushing guest sessions to storage, but only keep them in memory. Problably this could work out with the ideas mentioned by @slebetman.

Comment: @user826955 the idea of not saving new sessions that don't get modified during the lifetime of a request may be something that will already help you save a lot of file I/O.

Answer (score 0):

Use Redis for sessions storage and expire each session after one hour.

https://github.com/tj/connect-redis

Install necessary packages

```
npm install yarn
yarn add connect-redis, express, express-session, express, uid-safe
```

app.js

```
  var connectRedis = require('connect-redis')(expressSession),
    uid = require('uid-safe').sync
  sessionMiddleware = expressSession({
    genid: req => {
      if(req.session && req.session.uid)
        return req.session.uid + '_' + uid(24)
      return uid(24)
    },
    store: new connectRedis({
      port: 6379,
      ttl: 3600 // 1 hour
    }),
    secret: 'sfsa487838787we',
    name: 'live_session',
    rolling: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    proxy: true,
    logErrors: false,
    cookie: {
      path: '/',
      domain: '.yourdomain.io',
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: 'yourdomain.io',
      expires: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
      maxAge: 3600000
    }
```